# How to make a colored scoreboard header in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[image]

so how to make the white "Deaths" red without plugins

Comment: Good question. I first assumed it was a think with JSON text components in entity names (which is possible in 1.13+), but then I remembered that teams can have colors after searching for "color" on the "scoreboard" page of the Minecraft wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easy and straightforward, since the command accepts JSON in 1.13.

```
/scoreboard objectives modify <your objective> displayname {"text":"<your title>", "color":"<your color>"}
```

Or you can as well add a new objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add <name> <type> {"text":"<your title>", "color":"<your color>"}
```

In the example I've used this command:

```
/scoreboard objectives add MoreDeaths deathCount {"text":"More Deaths", "color":"yellow"}
```

These will result in this:
[image: Objective]

Answer (score 1):

This is a team color. You need a team with that color and the scoreboard holder has to join that team:

```
/team add teamName
/team modify teamName color blue
/team join teamName <selector>
```

Comment: I get that but how would I make the title (in the picture it’s deaths) to have a red color not  the names but the top text

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question. The answer by dly is correct.